# How to pre-render a Tab within BottomTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native

I'm using BottomTabNavigator for my React Native application. I've 4 tabs named TabA, TabB, TabC and TabD.
Basically, React Native render the tabs once they're focused however in my situation i would like to pre-render TabC even it's not focused jet so my question is how can i pre-render a Tab without focusing on it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check the help section (stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on how to improve your question (for example showing us what you have attempted so far).

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Thanks, I will try to describe as detail as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the lazy property to false.

By default, it will be set to true. So each tab will render only when appears on the screen.

You have to change it explicitly by

```
createBottomTabNavigator({
  viewProfile: ViewProfileScreen,
  calendar: CalendarScreen,
},
  lazy: false
);
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I've tried following your code but it didn't work, however, i've done some research and found this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/1.x/tab-navigator.html
As the documents we should place lazy property outside of tabBarOptions, after that it should work ^^.

Comment: I've modified the answer again. My previous answer is wrong. Please try this answer.

Comment: Marked now but is there away to pre-render a specific screen instead of all?